# Will Ubuntu/ROS recognize my R/C plane simulator joystick?

Tags: usb, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Phoenix aircraft simulator package which uses a USB adapter to allow my Toshiba R/C transmitter to be used as a joystick.

Will Ubuntu/ROS be able to find and use it?

Thanks,

Alan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43823/will-ubuntu/ros-recognize-my-r/c-plane-simulator-joystick?/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That depends on how it works on the hardware side. If it is a standard joystick device the joy package should work out of the box. You can just try it.

For more info please post some more details, e.g. the output of `dmesg` and `lsusb` after you plug the device.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you actually simulate a joystick that Ubuntu recognises, the joy package should work - maybe you need to install some package to recognise the "joystick" at the usb port, but if thats fine, there is a good chance ROS can find it too :-)

Just give it a try.

---

Originally posted by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) with karma: 342 on 2012-09-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on 2012-09-18**:
The Phoenix Joystick interface to my Futaba T7 radio is recognized by my PC as PxRC Phoenix RC USB interface  USB HID.  Ubuntu ROS electric didn't say anything when I plugged it in.  Where can I find out like I do in Device Manager under Windoz XP?  Alan

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-09-19**:
I'm not sure, if I remind correctly, but I'd suggest you try a sudo apt-get install joystick and hope that is enough to get the joystick running. Anyhow, under the presumption that your adapter works like a standard joystick, you can always google for instructions to make a joystick work on linux.